# How to lock Termux package environment version

Tags: android, termux

I want to lock my Termux package environment so that I can make different machines(same Android version) all have the same environment for better debugging.

First, I have checked [Termux packages](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages) it seems that do not provide archived version(always latest).
Second, I found [termux-create-package](https://github.com/termux/termux-create-package) and termux-apt-repo. But they only make a custom package.

```
$ pkg list-installed
Listing... Done
apt/stable,now 1.4.9-5 arm [installed]
bash/stable,now 5.0.7-2 arm [installed]
binutils/stable,now 2.32-3 arm [installed,automatic]
busybox/stable,now 1.30.1-2 arm [installed]
ca-certificates/stable,now 20190515 all [installed]
clang/stable,now 8.0.0-3 arm [installed]
command-not-found/stable,now 1.37 arm [installed]
curl/stable,now 7.65.1 arm [installed]
dash/stable,now 0.5.10.2-1 arm [installed]
diffutils/stable,now 3.7-1 arm [installed,automatic]
dpkg/stable,now 1.19.7 arm [installed]
game-repo/stable,now 1.0 all [installed]
gdbm/stable,now 1.18.1-1 arm [installed,automatic]
git/stable,now 2.22.0 arm [installed]
gnupg/stable,now 2.2.17 arm [installed,automatic]
gpgv/stable,now 2.2.17 arm [installed]
krb5/stable,now 1.16.3 arm [installed,automatic]
ldns/stable,now 1.7.0-5 arm [installed,automatic]
less/stable,now 551 arm [installed,automatic]
libandroid-glob/stable,now 0.4 arm [installed,automatic]
libandroid-support/stable,now 24-3 arm [installed]
libassuan/stable,now 2.5.3 arm [installed,automatic]
libbz2/stable,now 1.0.7 arm [installed]
libc++/stable,now 20 arm [installed]
libcrypt/stable,now 0.2-1 arm [installed]
libcrypt-dev/stable,now 0.2-1 arm [installed]
libcurl/stable,now 7.65.1 arm [installed]
libdb/stable,now 18.1.32 arm [installed,automatic]
libedit/stable,now 20190324-3.1-0 arm [installed,automatic]
libffi/stable,now 3.2.1-3 arm [installed]
libffi-dev/stable,now 3.2.1-3 arm [installed]
libgcrypt/stable,now 1.8.4 arm [installed]
libgpg-error/stable,now 1.36 arm [installed]
libiconv/stable,now 1.16-2 arm [installed]
libiconv-dev/stable,now 1.16-2 arm [installed]
libjpeg-turbo/stable,now 2.0.2-1 arm [installed,automatic]
libjpeg-turbo-dev/stable,now 2.0.2-1 arm [installed]
libksba/stable,now 1.3.5-1 arm [installed,automatic]
libllvm/stable,now 8.0.0-3 arm [installed]
liblzma/stable,now 5.2.4 arm [installed]
libnghttp2/stable,now 1.38.0 arm [installed]
libnpth/stable,now 1.6 arm [installed,automatic]
libsqlite/stable,now 3.28.0-2 arm [installed,automatic]
libutil/stable,now 0.4 arm [installed,automatic]
libxml2/stable,now 2.9.9-3 arm [installed]
libxml2-dev/stable,now 2.9.9-3 arm [installed]
libxslt/stable,now 1.1.33-1 arm [installed]
libxslt-dev/stable,now 1.1.33-1 arm [installed]
ncurses/stable,now 6.1.20190511-2 arm [installed]
ncurses-ui-libs/stable,now 6.1.20190511-2 arm [installed,automatic]
ndk-sysroot/stable,now 20 arm [installed,automatic]
openssh/stable,now 8.0p1-1 arm [installed]
openssl/stable,now 1.1.1c-1 arm [installed]
openssl-dev/stable,now 1.1.1c-1 arm [installed]
pcre2/stable,now 10.33 arm [installed,automatic]
pinentry/stable,now 1.1.0-4 arm [installed,automatic]
python/stable,now 3.7.4 arm [installed,automatic]
python-dev/stable,now 3.7.4 arm [installed]
readline/stable,now 8.0-1 arm [installed]
redis/stable,now 5.0.5 arm [installed]
science-repo/stable,now 1.0 all [installed]
sqlite/stable,now 3.28.0-2 arm [installed]
termux-am/stable,now 0.2 all [installed]
termux-auth/stable,now 1.1 arm [installed,automatic]
termux-exec/stable,now 0.3 arm [installed]
termux-keyring/stable,now 1.1 all [installed]
termux-licenses/stable,now 1.0 all [installed]
termux-tools/stable,now 0.68 all [installed]
tig/stable,now 2.4.1-3 arm [installed]
tsu/stable,now 2.3 all [installed]
vim/stable,now 8.1.1650 arm [installed]
vim-runtime/stable,now 8.1.1650 all [installed,automatic]
zlib/stable,now 1.2.11 arm [installed]
```

I want to lock these packages version.

Should I fork [Termux packages](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages) on my own package repo?
Or there is a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

Use the safest way to lock your termux
See: https://github.com/blackc8/termux-lock.git
you can install termux-lock with a single command

```
sh <(curl --silent https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blackc8/termux-lock/master/install.sh)
```